# How do I communicate using gql with Apollo websocket protocol

Tags: python, apollo, gql

I want to connect to the websocket. When I inspect the traffic between the client and the server I see that the first message is the handshake:

```
{"type": "connection_init",
 "payload":
           {
            "accept-language": "en",
            "ec-version": "5.1.88",
            "referrer": URL,
           }
}
```

Based on the format (the keys of the dict) I conclude that the websocket uses an Apollo websocket transport prototcol.

Next, I am following the websocket-[example](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/websockets.html) of `gql`'s documentation.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.websockets import WebsocketsTransport


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
async def main():
    transport = WebsocketsTransport(url=URL,
                                    init_payload={'accept-language': 'en',
                                                  'ec-version': '5.1.88'})
    async with Client(transport=transport,
                      fetch_schema_from_transport=False) as session:
        # do something
    

asyncio.run(main())
```

After reading more about the protocol [here](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md) I still don't understand how I can send messages to the server within my `Python`-script
How do I send the the below message to the websocket?

```
{
 "id": "1073897396",
 "type": "start",
 "operationName": operation,
 "eventId": 488
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EuropeanTour website does not use the Apollo websocket protocol for its API so you cannot use the standard WebsocketTransport class.

What I found out:

- instead of returning a `connection_ack` message after the `connection_init`, it returns a `wsIdentity` message
- for a subscription, the client will first send a start message containing an operationName and an eventId, without any GraphQL query
- the server will then answer with a `request-full-subscription` message, requiring the client to send the full subscription query
- the client has then to send a `full-subscription` message containing the full requested query, including the `operationName` and a new field `subscriptionName`
- the id is not actually random, it is generated from hashing together the `subscriptionName` and the variables, from a json format with the dictionary keys sorted. It took me a while to figure it out as no error is generated if the id is not correct
- the server seems to cache the GraphQL subscription based on the IP address probably so it will not request the subscription with a request-full-subscription message if it has already received it previously

Here is a Chrome screenshot showing the `request-full-subscription` messages:

[image: Chrome websocket messages]

You can then create your own transport by inheriting the `WebsocketTransport` class and making the necessary modifications.

Here is an example of working code:

```py
import asyncio
import json
import logging
from typing import Any, AsyncGenerator, Dict, Optional, Tuple

from graphql import DocumentNode, ExecutionResult, print_ast

from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.exceptions import TransportProtocolError
from gql.transport.websockets import WebsocketsTransport

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class EuropeanTourWebsocketsTransport(WebsocketsTransport):
    def _hash(self, e):
        t = 5381
        r = len(e)
        while r:
            r -= 1
            t = t * 33 ^ ord(e[r])
        return t & 0xFFFFFFFF

    def _calc_id(self, subscription_name, variables):

        obj = {
            "subscriptionName": subscription_name,
            "variables": variables,
        }

        obj_stringified = json.dumps(
            obj,
            separators=(",", ":"),
            sort_keys=True,
        )

        hashed_value = self._hash(obj_stringified)

        return hashed_value

    async def _send_query(
        self,
        document: DocumentNode,
        variable_values: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        operation_name: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> int:

        # Calculate the id by hashing the subscription name and the variables
        query_id = self._calc_id(self.latest_subscription_name, variable_values)

        # Creating the payload for the full subscription
        payload: Dict[str, Any] = {"query": print_ast(document)}
        if variable_values:
            payload["variables"] = variable_values
        if operation_name:
            payload["operationName"] = operation_name
            payload["subscriptionName"] = self.latest_subscription_name

        # Saving the full query first and waiting for the server to request it later
        self.saved_full_subscriptions[str(query_id)] = payload

        # Then first start to request the subscription only with the operation name
        query_str = json.dumps(
            {
                "id": str(query_id),
                "type": "start",
                "operationName": operation_name,
                "eventId": self.latest_event_id,
            }
        )

        await self._send(query_str)

        return query_id

    async def subscribe(
        self,
        document: DocumentNode,
        *,
        variable_values: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        operation_name: str,
        subscription_name: str,
        event_id: int,
        send_stop: Optional[bool] = True,
    ) -> AsyncGenerator[ExecutionResult, None]:

        self.latest_event_id = event_id
        self.latest_subscription_name = subscription_name

        async for result in super().subscribe(
            document,
            variable_values=variable_values,
            operation_name=operation_name,
            send_stop=send_stop,
        ):
            yield result

    async def _wait_ack(self) -> None:

        self.saved_full_subscriptions = {}

        while True:
            init_answer = await self._receive()

            answer_type, answer_id, execution_result = self._parse_answer(init_answer)

            if answer_type == "wsIdentity":
                return

            raise TransportProtocolError(
                "Websocket server did not return a wsIdentity response"
            )

    def _parse_answer(
        self, answer: str
    ) -> Tuple[str, Optional[int], Optional[ExecutionResult]]:
        try:
            json_answer = json.loads(answer)
        except ValueError:
            raise TransportProtocolError(
                f"Server did not return a GraphQL result: {answer}"
            )

        if "wsIdentity" in json_answer:
            return ("wsIdentity", json_answer["wsIdentity"], None)

        elif (
            "type" in json_answer and json_answer["type"] == "request-full-subscription"
        ):
            return ("request-full-subscription", json_answer["id"], None)

        else:

            return self._parse_answer_apollo(json_answer)

    async def send_full_subscription(self, answer_id: str):

        if answer_id not in self.saved_full_subscriptions:
            raise Exception(f"Full subscription not found for id {answer_id}")

        payload = self.saved_full_subscriptions[answer_id]

        query_str = json.dumps(
            {"id": answer_id, "type": "full-subscription", "payload": payload}
        )

        await self._send(query_str)

    async def _handle_answer(
        self,
        answer_type: str,
        answer_id: Optional[int],
        execution_result: Optional[ExecutionResult],
    ) -> None:

        if answer_type == "request-full-subscription":
            await self.send_full_subscription(answer_id)

        else:
            await super()._handle_answer(answer_type, answer_id, execution_result)


async def main():

    transport = EuropeanTourWebsocketsTransport(
        url="wss://btec-websocket.services.imgarena.com",
        init_payload={
            "accept-language": "en",
            "ec-version": "5.1.88",
            "operator": "europeantour",
            "referrer": "https://www.europeantour.com/",
            "sport": "GOLF",
        },
    )

    async with Client(
        transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False
    ) as session:

        query = gql(
            """
subscription ShotTrackerSubscribeToGolfTournamentGroupScores($input: SubscribeToGolfTournamentGroupScoresInput!) {
  subscribeToGolfTournamentGroupScores(input: $input) {
    groupId
    l1Course
    teamId
    players {
      id
      lastName
      firstName
    }
    roundScores {
      courseId
      roundNo
      toParToday {
        value
      }
      holesThrough {
        value
      }
      startHole
      holes {
        holePar
        holeStrokes
        holeOrder
        holeNumber
      }
      isPlayoff
    }
    toPar {
      value
    }
    tournamentPosition {
      format
      value
      displayValue
    }
    status
  }
}
"""
        )

        variables = {
            "input": {
                "teamId": 21,
                "tournamentId": 488,
                "roundNo": 4,
            },
        }

        async for result in session.subscribe(
            query,
            operation_name="ShotTrackerSubscribeToGolfTournamentGroupScores",
            variable_values=variables,
            subscription_name="subscribeToGolfTournamentGroupScores",
            event_id=488,
        ):

            print(result)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Good catch. I thought this was a custom implementation indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: @leszek.hanusz I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850345/how-to-send-and-receive-queries-with-a-custom-gql-transport) regarding queries and the same protocol. Can you take a look

Answer (score 1):

Considering the JSON message you provided:

```json
{
    "id": "1073897396",
    "type": "start",
    "operationName": "SubscribeToGolfTournamentStatus",
    "eventId": 488
}
```

The `operationName` suggests that you are trying to start a subscription named `SubscribeToGolfTournamentStatus`. You would need the actual GraphQL subscription query that this name refers to.

So in your case, to send a message to the WebSocket, you will typically need to execute a GraphQL subscription. In the context of the Apollo WebSocket protocol and using the `gql` library, you will use the [`session.subscribe()`](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html#gql.client.AsyncClientSession.subscribe) method.

Let's assume the subscription query looks like this (this is just a placeholder, you would need the real subscription query structure):

```
subscription SubscribeToGolfTournamentStatus($eventId: Int!) {
    golfTournamentStatus(eventId: $eventId) {
        ...YourDesiredFieldsHere
    }
}
```

Here is how you would send that subscription using `gql`:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.websockets import WebsocketsTransport

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

async def main():
    transport = WebsocketsTransport(url='wss://btec-websocket.services.imgarena.com',
                                    init_payload={
                                        'accept-language': 'en',
                                        'ec-version': '5.1.88',
                                        'operator': 'europeantour',
                                        'referrer': 'https://www.europeantour.com/',
                                        'sport': 'GOLF'
                                    })
    async with Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False) as session:
        
        # Define the subscription
        subscription = gql('''
        subscription SubscribeToGolfTournamentStatus($eventId: Int!) {
            golfTournamentStatus(eventId: $eventId) {
                ...YourDesiredFieldsHere
            }
        }
        ''')

        # Subscribe and handle incoming data
        async for result in session.subscribe(subscription, variable_values={"eventId": 488}):
            print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

That would:

- define the GraphQL subscription with the `gql` function (Remember, you will need to replace the placeholder GraphQL query with the actual structure you are targeting).
  You can see an example in [`leszekhanusz/gql-actioncable`](https://github.com/leszekhanusz/gql-actioncable).
- use the `session.subscribe()` method to start the subscription and pass the necessary variables (`eventId` in this case).
- set up an asynchronous loop to handle incoming data from the subscription.

Compared to the [official example](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/websockets.html):

- in both case cases, you initialize the [`WebsocketsTransport`](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/websockets.html) with a given URL and payload, and then create a [`Client`](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html) session.
- the "`do something`" part of the example is expanded to specifically show how you would execute a subscription query with the `gql` library.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your methodology earlier but it returns a `gql.transport.exceptions.TransportProtocolError: Server did not return a GraphQL result`. Therefore, I thought I maybe communicated in the wrong way. Please check my updated question

Comment: @HJA24 Where does the `"type":"full-subscription"` come from? It is not common in typical GraphQL websocket implementations. That would indicate the server might be expecting a custom websocket protocol rather than the standard one.

Comment: I am not sure. I see it after visiting the website with Google Chrome, clicking on a player so the course becomes visible -> Network -> WS -> Click on `wss://btec-websocket.services.imgarena.com/` and lastly check the messages

Comment: The server might use a custom protocol for its Websockets. Instead of the usual `start `message for subscriptions that many GraphQL servers expect, it might expect a `full-subscription` type. If that is the case, you might need to implement your own transport using the websockets library to communicate with the server. May be first try and use the [Improved Apollo Client Devtools](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/improved-apollo-client-devtools-eb43258f103f/) to see more of your transactions.

Comment: The first message to the server after the handshake is `{"id":"1073897396","type":"start","operationName":"SubscribeToGolfTournamentStatus","eventId":488}`. There is no query.  How do I send this to the server using the `gql`-functions?

Comment: @HJA24 Not sure, considering the `gql` library is designed to work with standard GraphQL over WebSocket protocols. If the server you are interacting with expects a custom sequence of messages or has a unique protocol, you might run into limitations when using `gql`.